# How to compile and configure zen 4.2 from source code?

Tags: 12.04, xen

I have downloaded Xen 4.2 source code from GIT. Now I want to compile Xen from the source code on ubuntu 12 or 14. I have followed all these steps in the following link (https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Compiling_Xen_From_Source). But I am unable to install Xen. Kindly I need your help.

Comment: Can you please provide more information (like log files and description) regarding what step is not working ? or what kind of problem you facing right now ? 
Please remember: "A problem well stated is a problem half-solved." Charles Kettering

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the ((https://wiki.xenproject.org wiki/Compiling_Xen_From_Source)). 
1)   I want to update the following file but It has some problem.It's not   opening
   Updated /sbin/installkernel on Linux
   CONFIG_XEN_DOM0=y
   CONFIG_XEN_PRIVILEGED_GUEST=y

2) I want to check the .config file by using cat .config but it also not exists